# VS2015 is throwing an exception while adding a new Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 is throwing an exception while I want to add a new Entity Data Model.
I want to a create Model from DB but when I click on the button `"New Connection..."`, Visual Studio is throwing the following exception.

[image]

Comment: Which VS version ?

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention. My version is VS 2015.

Comment: Why is this question at +2?

Comment: @Aars93: because people find it worth it. If you disagree, please flag the question and suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I usually delete the old (usually all) database connections from my Data Sources window when such a thing occurs. After deleting the old connections Visual Studio will let you to add a new one.

[image: delete this level]